# What is the easiest way to find message IDs of Matlab warnings?

Tags: matlab

All Matlab warnings have message ID. It can be found using the in-built lastwarn method, for example:

```
>> A=zeros(6,6); inv(A); [~,msgID] = lastwarn

Warning: Matrix is singular to working precision. 

 msgID =

'MATLAB:singularMatrix'
```

But this works only when the specific warning is available at hand.
If a simulation produces lots of different warnings, how do I get their message IDs? Going through simulation and pausing it to use lastwarn doesn't seem handy. Is it possible to configure the in-built warning method to print out the message IDs?

Comment: Not exactly quick, but looking into the function which throws the warnings one can find the warning IDs in the code at the point where they are raised (usually input warnings are at the beginning, and output warnings at the end)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`warning`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/warning.html) function has a few useful flags which can be used. For your purpose, somewhere at the top of your code or in the console, type:

```
warning ON VERBOSE
```

or the equivalent:

```
warning('on','verbose')
```

Which according to the documentation:

> WARNING ON VERBOSE and WARNING OFF VERBOSE control the displaying of
>   an extra line of helpful text containing the warning identifier when a
>   warning is displayed.

---

With this flag set, you'll get the msg ID of every warning (no need to call `lastwarn`):

```
>> A=zeros(6,6); inv(A);
Warning: Matrix is singular to working precision.
(Type "warning off MATLAB:singularMatrix" to suppress this warning.)
```

Comment: You're right. I tried that several times but it didn't display the additional line. Now after re-starting Matlab it does. Seems I screwed up my Matlab settings somehow.